# Get Portlet Session on server

Tags: java, session, portlet

My question is:

I have two different *Portlets* (nothing but war file) deployed in a portal server called first and second; whenever user clicks *firstportlet* (first) I use the following code to set `session` object!:

**Code in first portlet:**

```java
String application="Welcome";
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) webAppAccess
                    .getHttpServletRequest()
                    .getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST);
portletRequest.getPortletSession(true).setAttribute("application",
                        sessionValue, 
                        PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

log.Info("SESSION hole value:---" + portletRequest.getPortletSession(false));
```

Whenever user clicks secondportlet(second) I am using follwing code to retrieve the `session` which was set in firstportlet.

**Code in second portlet:**

```java
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) webAppAccess
                    .getHttpServletRequest()
                    .getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST);


log.Info("SESSION hole value:---"+ portletRequest.getPortletSession(false));
log.Info("SESSION VALUE in second Portlet:----"
    + portletRequest.getPortletSession(false).getAttribute("application",
                             PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE));
```

**Error:**

But in second portlet I am always getting `null` value, please any solution?

Comment: Which portlet container are using?

Answer (score 0):

The `portletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE` mechanism makes it possible for portlets to share session data if they are within the same portlet application. If you have two portlets that are not in the same `war` they are not in the same portlet application and thus, the session data is not shared either.

To solve this you need to put the two portlets into the same portlet application (same `war`, same `portlet.xml` but still two different portlets).

Comment: how can i do this any example ?

Comment: That depends, but basically you put all the portlet code and resources in to the same war and then merge the portlet.xml so that it contains the definition of both the portlets. If you need a more detailed example than that it would probably help if we knew what you use to code your portlets.

Comment: What tool are you using for developing your portlets?

Comment: WEF8 tool using to developing portlets.

Comment: Don't know everything about that tool, but you should be able to add a second portlet to the first portlet application project through a wizard.

Comment: i don't know abt that can you help me out for the same.

Comment: I am not using WEF, but you have tutorials here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRUWN_8.0.0/com.bowstreet.designer.doc_8.0.0/designer/c_learning_wpf.htm

Answer (score 0):

DanielBarbarian's answer is correct. To share the global session, the portlets need to be in the same war. But there are other ways to share data between portlets on the same page, but not necessarily in the same war. (I'm assuming your portal container supports the JSR286 standard)

- Use interportlet communication. This can notify other portlets of events. It is a simple publish/subscribe system that is not difficult to set up.
- Use global render parameters.

There are examples on the web for both options.

Comment: can ypu provide link  for seeing example?